# php - Count number of *.txt files in folder

Tags: php

We have a folder **newfolder** , inside this folder we have *.jpg *.rar *.txt files 
We need get number only of *.txt files , and if no *.txt file exist echo **There is no *.txt file here**:

```
<?php
$numberoftxt = count(glob("*.txt"));
if ($numberoftxt > 0){
echo 'There is '.$numberoftxt.' files;
} else {
echo 'There is no *.txt file here';
}
?>
```

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: missing single quote ' after .' files

Comment: Why do you call `count(glob(..))` twice and don't use $numberoftxt?

Comment: The question there is syntax error how to fix it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error at the line with echo "thereis ... missing single quote '.

Here is the repaired solution for you:

```
$directory = ''; //specifiy path to directory
$files = glob($directory."*.txt");
$fileNum = count($files);
if($fileNum){
   echo 'There is'.$fileNum.' .txt files';
}
else {
   echo "no .txt files found.";
}
```

Comment: I'm using the php file inside the same directory

Comment: so $directory = dirname(\_\_FILE\_\_).'/';

Answer (score 1):

missing `single quote` ' after `.' files`

needs to be

```
echo 'There is '.$numberoftxt.' files';
```